# Suhel Seth said "We will endure the ethos of our civilization"

Tags: word-meaning, transitivity

I am watching a speech by Suhel Seth, and one line strikes me as odd.

> The point is if we do it quickly, if we do it with alacrity, we will be safe as a nation, but more importantly, we will **endure the ethos of our civilization**.

Both the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/endure) and [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/endure) state unequivocally that the transitive usage of **endure** means *to suffer something unpleasant*. It is clear that Suhel Seth tried to use this word to mean *make something last*. Is that a mistake on his part or a rare usage?

I am not sure he is saying here the Indian ethos as a civilization is a bad that needs to be endured. The speech is available on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/wME3c2wr3As?t=4m38s), and this link will take you to the sentence in question.

Comment: **ethos** is the  *Zeitgeist*, and when you are out-of-step with your times, it is something to be endured and possibly *survived*.  It doesn't mean "to cause {something} to last, to make it enduring".  If the prevailing ethos is to spew carbon dioxide into the atmosphere with no regard for the consequences, then that ethos is something we may pray humankind may **endure**, i.e. "survive".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I am not sure _endure_ and _survive_ mean the same thing though, dude(ss). My understanding is _to survive something_ means "to live through something", and, as it were, "to see the light at the end of the tunnel". With _endure_, in my mind, the tunnel has no end.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Also, I agree the _Geist_ of the time can be negative and unpleasant, but don't most people use the word **ethos** to mean something positive and worth preserving? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethos) defines it as _a character used to describe the guiding beliefs or ideals that characterize a community, nation, or ideology._ How does a people survive or suffer ideals?

Comment: **ethos** need not be limited to *ideals*.  It does not necessarily imply approbation. It's roughly synonymous with **outlook** or **core principles**, whatever those may be. We should not be surprised to find a journal article entitled *The Ethos of Waste* or *The Ethos of Acceptable Collateral Damage*.

Comment: Oh, I see; ***I think he means***:  "the ethos of our civilization will endure"" (last; not end). Please note: spontaneous speech acts often lead to oddities. So, the way he said it is a mistake in terms of his intended meaning. Or: ***we will make the ethos of our civilization endure***. His making a call to action. He just said it incorrectly. It happens all the time.

Comment: Not all transitive-verb definitions of _endure_ mention hardship. [Wordnik](http://wordnik.com/words/endure) lists _To remain firm under; to sustain; to undergo; to support without breaking or yielding_.

Comment: It makes no difference that it means to remain firm. If you are talking about a society breaking part due to social strife, you would not then talk about "enduring the ethos of a civilization". It has to be: the ethos of our civilization will endure i.e. remain firm.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a "call to action":

> I believe that you can't survive this way. And something must give.
>   The point is if we do it quickly, if we do it with alacrity, we will
>   be safe as a nation, but more importantly, we will endure the ethos of
>   our civilization.

However, **the speech contains a typical mistake that can occur when speaking spontaneously**. This one is mis-phrasing or leaving out a word:

The only thing that makes sense here is:

> The point is if we do it quickly, if we do it with alacrity, we will
>   be safe as a nation, but more importantly, we will make the ethos of
>   our civilization endure.

OR

> The point is if we do it quickly, if we do it with alacrity, we will
>   be safe as a nation, but more importantly, the ethos of our
>   civilization will endure.

The reason is this: giving the first part of the sentence here, he could not have meant: we will endure (suffer) the ethos of our civilization.

Answer (score 0):

Colloquially, the meaning of endure has changed *slightly* towards your second definition. But it sound like he means "to suffer", just without the unpleasant aspect.